# SQL: Equi Joins with OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to do an equi join with multiple OR criteria but haven't seemed to be able to figure it out. Below is what I am working with so far. I am hoping to find all records where the two p_numbers match first and then return cases where the g_id equals the p_number for instances where the p_numbers did not match. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
FROM T1, T2 
WHERE ( T1.p_number = T2.p_number OR T1.g_id = T2.p_number)
```

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2)  Why are you using archaic join syntax?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). They *were* superseded 28 years, ago; there is no reason to use that 31 year old syntax any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.p_number = T2.p_number WHERE ((T1.p_number = T2.p_number) OR ((T1.p_number != T2.p_number) AND (T1.g_id = T2.p_number)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @a table(col1 int, col2 int);
insert into @a(col1, col2) values (1, 100), (200, 2), (1, 1000);

declare @b table(col1 int, col2 int);
insert into @b(col1, col2) values (1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 100);

select *
from @a as a, @b as b
where (a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col1) or (a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 <> b.col2) or (a.col2 = b.col1);
```